# Redis - How store and Array of Data

Tags: redis

I'm new to Redis and I'm not sure what is the best data structure to use in this situation.

Each user will send a heartbeat (every 5 seconds) to say they are still online.

The data stored with be the userID and the date/time.

Previously in Memcached I would just store a string for each user - say userid-active with datatime as the value.

But I know I will need to query all the active users data at the same time and wanted to know what would be the best method to store this. (maybe an array structure).

Any advise would be very welcome.

thankyou

Answer (score 0):

If you use a sorted set you could then fetch a time interval of active users. Latest hour, day and so on.

```
ZADD active_users [user-id] [timestamp]
```

To fetch users active within an hour:

```
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE active_users +inf [currtime]-3600
```